# MySQL distinct first column, random second column

Tags: mysql, random, distinct

I need to select distinct values from column A in the database, and then randomise the result associated with column A in column B.

In the below example:

```
Year    Filename
1973    1.jpg
1973    2.jpg
1973    3.jpg
1973    4.jpg
1975    5.jpg
1975    6.jpg
1975    7.jpg
1975    8.jpg
```

The result I'm looking for would be to always show the distinct values in Column A, and then randomly select a value associated with that from Column B.

So first page load might produce result:

```
Year    Filename
1973    1.jpg
1975    5.jpg
```

But refresh page load might then produce result:

```
Year    Filename
1973    3.jpg
1975    8.jpg
```

1973 and 1975 will always each appear once, but what the second field is will vary with every page load.

This is my attempt but it is executing around 1 second:

```
SELECT DISTINCT year, (SELECT DISTINCT filename from photogallery WHERE year = year ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1) as filename FROM photogallery GROUP BY year ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `DISTINCT`s are superfluous and you must use table aliases so that the engine knows the table the `year` column belongs to. Right now the `WHERE` clause in the inner query is as good as none as it's always true.

```
SELECT pg1.year,
      (SELECT pg2.filename
              FROM photogallery pg2
              WHERE pg2.year = pg1.year
              ORDER BY rand()
              LIMIT 1) AS filename
      FROM photogallery pg1 
      GROUP BY pg1.year
      ORDER BY 1;
```

Comment: Come on sb; we're better than this

Comment: @Strawberry: What? The question isn't a downright gem... but it has everything, table/sample data (though not as DDL and DML which I prefer), expected results and an attempt, so it's just good enough... Or if that's not it, have I overlooked some silly mistake? If, then I cannot spot it, honestly.

Comment: @stickybit Thank you, you have helped me and I have learnt something. Hopefully the question helps someone else in the future.